# Show first and last page only when there is more than one page number using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons like this:

```
 <button class="next_prev" onclick="" id="first_buttons" disabled>{{ pages.first }}</button>
<button class="next_prev" onclick="" id="last_buttons" disabled>{{ pages.last }}</button>
```

If there is only one page by default the page {{ pages.first }} and {{ pages.last }} store the page number 1 and 1 and show it. But I only want to show these two buttons if page number is great than 1. I get page length like this:

```
<p> <span>{% get_pages %} {{ pages|length }} pages</span> </p>
```

Can it be done in jquery  or javascript? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the wrapper of the page length number with a class/ID. For example:

```
<p id="num-of-pages"><span>{% get_pages %} {{ pages|length }} pages</span></p>
```

If the output of the above code only churns out some numbers only, you can use this jQuery code below to hide the buttons:

```
var numOfPages = $('#num-of-pages').text();

if (numOfPages <= 1 ){
    $('.next_prev').hide();
}
```

Example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/56kbj/

PS: Just a tip - since .next_prev is quite a generic name and you  might have used this class for some other elements, better to give some IDs to those two buttons that you want to hide.

**UPDATE (Based on user2032220's second comment):**

If `{% get_pages %} {{ pages|length }}` actually output "Pages 1" then one of the easiest solution is to wrap the page length in another span tag. For example:

```
<p id="num-of-pages"><span>{% get_pages %} <span>{{ pages|length }}</span></span></p>
```

Then the code to hide the buttons would be to change:

```
var numOfPages = $('#num-of-pages span span').text();
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/56kbj/1/

Comment: The problem is there's a string "pages" in num-of-pages id. When I remove pages it works but I want pages to be shown in the template?

Comment: See "UPDATE (Based on user2032220's second comment):" on the edited answer box above.

Comment: No pages|length outputs only page number but since I want pages to be show after that I manually added pages string in the template.

Comment: Based on the "UPDATE (Based on user2032220's second comment):" answer, are you now clear what to modify on your end to make it work then?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a common class to each button, e.g:

```
<button class="next_prev pageNumberBtn" onclick="" id="first_buttons" disabled>{{ pages.first }}</button>

<button class="next_prev pageNumberBtn" onclick="" id="last_buttons" disabled>{{ pages.last }}</button>
```

Then hide the buttons if the last page number is 1:

```
if ($('#last_buttons').html() == '1') {
    $('.pageNumberBtn').hide();
}
```